# I'm confused about the aerodynamics of a gas turbine compressor blade of a jet engine?

Tags: pressure, aerodynamics, aircraft

I have a few questions here-

1. Why do you need an increase in static pressure, why not total pressure?
2. The rotor vane increase total energy, is this energy converted into kinetic energy or total pressure or both? And then the stator vanes increase the static pressure.

Comment: Migrate to [Aviation SE](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: @StephemG I already did and those question were not answered.

Comment: Why do you need an increase in static pressure for what? Also, the rotor vane increases total energy of what?

Comment: @probably_someone the static pressure of the fluid, beucase I asked on Avation stack exchange that and they said it make for good combustion conditions, why?

Comment: @Itzyoboi that increases the oxygen concentration. At high altitudes the air is thinner, so pressurizing it ensures that you'll have enough oxygen to keep a flame lit.

Comment: No, you did not ask on Aviation SE. I checked all your 10 questions there, and this one is not among them. Or do you hide behind several identities?

Comment: I believe OP is referring to [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/45360/21091). There is some persistent confusion about the function of the stator vanes. They do absolutely nothing, except untwisting the flow.

Comment: @Koyovis … which is pretty important for the efficiency of the next stage. But that question is from a certain Gary Zanger, not Itzyoboi.

Comment: @PeterKämpf both accounts are mine, I don't know why I made two I think I forgot the password for Gary so I made a new account until I logged in with some device that automaticly had me logged in so I use both, so I don't use 7 accounts, I use 2.

Comment: @SeeJianShin so increasing total pressure doesn't increase oxygen concentration?

Answer (score 2):

Total pressure is static plus dynamic pressure. A compressor will increase both (total and static pressure) together. Note that the flow speed in the different compressor stages is [nearly constant](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/114280/why-do-turbine-engines-work/159822#159822) and the flow is only decelerated for combustion after the last compressor stage in an area called [diffusor](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/279473/how-does-a-diffuser-increase-fluid-pressure).

The flow speed in the compressor is chosen such that you just avoid supersonic flow at the blade tips but maintain enough dynamic pressure so throughput is maximized and the whole engine can be built smaller. Supersonic compressor flow incurs higher losses and reduces efficiency.

Who says the stator vanes increase the pressure of the flow? They do not move, so they hardly can do work on the flow. All they do is to control swirl such that the direction of flow is optimised for the next stage. Note that compressor blades have very thin airfoils which work best at a distinct angle of attack. Higher variations in angle of attack would require a blunter nose shape and a thicker airfoil. This is similar to a slotted flap at the trailing edge of a wing. The stator vane is like the wing in that respect that it directs the flow in one direction, allowing a thin airfoil behind it.

The rotor vane then increases both total and static energy.

Comment: ok how does the static pressure increase if you said the stator vanes only untwist the flow? One more question, the dynamic pressure gets it's pressure from the mechanical work being done on it by the rotor blades, correct?

Comment: @Itzyoboi: Again, static vanes do not increase static pressure. This is all done by the rotor vanes. As you say, they do mechanical work on the air which results in a pressure increase.

Comment: Ok, But I thought static pressure was the pressure of something when it's stationary, but the rotor vanes are rotating so wouldn't it be increasesing the dynamic pressure? Thanks.